# Conditional execution of Maxima chunks in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, maxima

I have a file which is meant to dynamically create exercises.
In this file I use R for statistical calculations and random number generation and Maxima as CAS through the R library `rim`, using the following basic setup.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(digits=2)
library(xtable)
library(rim)
library(reticulate)  ## better Python in R
maxima.options(engine.format = "latex", 
           engine.label = TRUE,
           inline.format = "latex", 
           inline.label = FALSE)
```

I then want to switch between different functions for an exercise by randomly generating a switch through

```
switch1<-FALSE;switch2<-FALSE
exercise<-sample(1:2,1)
switch(exercise,
       switch1<-TRUE,
       switch2<-TRUE)

print(c(switch1,switch2)) # check that only one is TRUE and the other FALSE
```

Then I hand this logical switch to the eval option of the respective Maxima chunk.

````
```{maxima eval=switch1,echo=FALSE}
f:1/(x-4)+1/(y+2)+4^2*x+4*y-3;
````

````
```{maxima eval=switch2,echo=FALSE}
f:3/(2*x+1)-1/y+6*x-4*y+2;
````

However, both statements are evaluated, as if I did not set a switch, even though one is FALSE. When I use a chunk with R as the programming language, the switching works - only the maxima chunk does not work.

Could anyone help me solve the problem of properly switching on the Maxima chunks.

Comment: Thank you. It worked on my system. I tried your alternative and still have the same issue that the R chunk is switched on and off, but the maxima chunk is not.

Comment: I think the `switch` statement is actually technically correct (but weird), FWIW

Comment: It was originally intended for more than 2 cases where nested if statements start getting tedious. I just tried to simplify the problem.

Comment: if the `eval` worked as expected I think you could use something of the form `eval=(which_switch == 1)`, `eval=(which_switch==2)`, etc.. But that's tangential.  As a way of troubleshooting it might be worth checking whether `eval` works properly in the context of `python` chunks (which are more mainstream/widely used), or whether it's a maxima/`rim`-specific problem.

Comment: It seem like this may be specific to `rim` -- you might try submitting a ticket the issue tracker for that project.

Comment: Trying the switch with python works as well, so it is maxima/rim specific. I will report it there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

Thanks for opening the issue!

This [*was*](https://github.com/rcst/rim/issues/27) a `rim` specific problem: Basically, chunk option `eval` was ignored before version`0.5.1`. See examples on the current (`0.6.3`) [vignette page](https://rcst.github.io/rim/#chunk-options).

Your case should work as expected with the latest version.